# How to fix my: TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

New to python and I keep getting this error when I try running my code. This is the code I'm trying to run

```
table=[0]*3
column=0
n=0
with open('matrix.txt','r') as f:
    numbers=f.read()
    numbers=[int(x) for x in numbers.split()]
    for i in range(3):
        table[column]=[0]*3
        for j in range(3):
            table[i][j]=numbers[n]
            n+=1
    column+=1
print(table)
```

I want to make a 3x3 table of the contents in my file. the file contents are;

```
2 3 4 1 2 6 9 8 9
```

I keep getting the error message when I run it. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: i think you should iterate `column` and not `collumn` line before the last one

Comment: Do you want a list of list? something like [[2,3,4], [1,2,5]...] right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing the column outside of the outer for loop. Moreover, it is misspelled.

Comment: this answer is the right one, fix your indent and the column and with it the code works fine for me

Answer (score 4):

You make it more complicated than it has to be:

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 9, 8, 9]
table = [numbers[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
import numpy as np 
with open('matrix.txt','r') as f:
    numbers=f.read()
    table =np.array([int(x) for x in numbers.split()]).reshape((3,3))
print(table)
```

if you really insist that your table is not a numpy array just convert it to a list:

```
table = table.tolist()
```